# PHP and print the index number of the clicked button

Tags: php

I have very simple HTML page with two buttons. I can click one of those buttons. I want to print the index number of the clicked button.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<button name="key[3]" type="submit">Click me</button>
<button name="key[4]" type="submit">Click me</button>
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
$keys = array_keys($_POST['key']);

echo $keys[0];
```

This will output either 3 or 4.

How could I do this better? I think my way does not offer nice coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to name them as `key[3]`, `key[4]` etc. Simply use `key` for all of your button's `name` attribute and assign distinct `value` in each of your button. That way it would be much easy for you catch the key of the pressed button.

```
<button name="key" type="submit" value="3">Click me</button>
<button name="key" type="submit" value="4">Click me</button>
```

And `echo $_POST['key'];` would print either `3` or `4` based on the pressed button.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a foreach loop over the array, echoing a button with the respective name each time.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($keys as $key) {
  echo "<button name='$key[$i]' type='submit'>Click me</button>";
  i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to print the index number of the clicked button. I do not want to print the buttons.